# Limit of AWS Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm bit confused here after reading the below link on Amazon SQS. I wanted to know, what is the limit of FIFO queue?
As per the mentioned link, the max count of inflight messages should not be more than 20k which means, the maximum number of messages consumer would be receiving & would not be deleted, but what about the unprocessed messages which have not been received?

[https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#:~:text=A%20single%20Amazon%20SQS%20message,20%2C000%20for%20a%20FIFO%20queue](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#:%7E:text=A%20single%20Amazon%20SQS%20message,20%2C000%20for%20a%20FIFO%20queue)

Answer (score 2):

The [link](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#:%7E:text=A%20single%20Amazon%20SQS%20message,20%2C000%20for%20a%20FIFO%20queue) you provided explains that there is no limit:

> A single Amazon SQS message queue can contain an **unlimited number** of messages.

The only limit is for **inflight messages**:

> However, there is a 120,000 quota for the number of inflight messages for a standard queue and 20,000 for a FIFO queue.

Though in **theory** the limit would be the number of messages you can [submit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-messages.html) within retention period. So for FIFO you can submit maximum 3000 messages per second. Multiply this by total retention time (max 14 days), and you will get your limit:

```
3000 * 14*24*3600 = 3.6288e+09
```